# EagerTensor object has no attribute 'astype'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am using trained tf model output (TF 2.8) and trying to convert it to numpy array.

```
trained_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
output = trained_model(features)[index]
output.numpy()
```

But somehow in the process of converting the EagerTensor to Numpy array it tries to apply `around` function(I don't know why). And hence the following error arises:

```
/opt/conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/numpy_ops/np_array_ops.py:738: in around
    AttributeError: EagerTensor object has no attribute 'astype'. 
    E               If you are looking for numpy-related methods, please run the following:
    E               from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
    E               np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
```

What can I do here?

P.S. `np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()` doesn't work

UPD: Type of tensor : `type: <dtype: 'float32'>  <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>   tf.Tensor(78400.01, shape=(), dtype=float32)`

Comment: print(tf.shape(output))?

Comment: It's tf.shape(())